# using text box value in different action with same controller in mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I am new to mvc5,
i want to use the value of text box from login view in different action in the same controller,
all the example i seen take the value to one action using BeginForm()
is there is any way to do that?

the login view:
[image]

and i want to perform this action:

[image]

I am try to use TempData but it return empty page

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aIbGe.png):

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please post the relevant code and use it to elaborate your problem?

Comment: Edit your question (not in comments).

Comment: Go to the help files and read the section on 'Asking'. Adding code in linked images is not acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand what your exact requirement is. However BeginForm() has many overloads. like BeginForm(actionName, conttrollername). If you simply want to post the data to different action method then you may use this overload

```
@Html.BeginForm(actionName, conttrollername)
```

Comment: ok, but i don't know where i should write it in login View
i try to overload it but no result accurs

Comment: do you mind to explain exactly what are you trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I Understand you difficult question. You want to use data provided by login in another action to render another page.

Use this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ConfirmRegistration(string username, string password)
{
    try
    {
        DoRegistration(username, password);

        //automatically login user after registration
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.UserName, user.RememberMe); 

        //after successful login, redirect to UserPage and render UserPage page
        return RedirectToAction("UserPage", new{username = username, password = password});
    }
    catch(YourLoginFailedExceptioOrWhatEver)
    {    
        return View(username); //login failed, go back to login page      
    }              
}

public ActionResult UserPage(string username, string password)
{
     .......
     return View(information);
}
```

Comment: thanks alot, but not this which i want :(,
 when the user enter correct username and password he will enter the home page
 which i do
 the problem is
 i need to create tab in this home page to let the user enter his profie(userPage)
 and so i need the value he enters first time to browse his information from database